Anonymous splat (*) vs argument forwarding (...) for IGNORING arguments in Ruby
I'd like to write a method whose purpose is to totally ignore its arguments. I could use an anonymous splat or argument forwarding, but it's not clear which one is more idiomatic or performant in Ruby:

The splat implies the arguments will be allocated inside an Array (which I won't use). e.g.:

def method_missing(*)
  nil
end


Argument forwarding implies I want to call another method (which I won't call) e.g.:

def method_missing(...)
  nil
end

For the reasons cited above, neither option seems very idiomatic. Does anyone with knowledge of Ruby's internals have a better idea which method is more idiomatic, or at least more performant and efficient? Please note my purpose is to ignore the arguments.
I ran this benchmark below several times with ruby 3.3.5 (YJIT disabled). The execution time between methods was almost the same, but memory usage varied too wildly in each run to be conclusive.
require 'benchmark'
require 'objspace'

class SplatExample
  def method_missing(*)
    'Yay!'
  end
end

class ForwardingExample
  def method_missing(...)
    'Yay!'
  end
end

splat_instance = SplatExample.new
forwarding_instance = ForwardingExample.new

def measure_memory
  ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
end

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report("Splat:") do
    initial_memory = measure_memory
    10_000_000.times { splat_instance.example(1, 2, 3) }
    puts "Memory used: #{measure_memory - initial_memory} bytes"
  end

   x.report("Forwarding:") do
    initial_memory = measure_memory
    10_000_000.times { forwarding_instance.example(1, 2, 3) }
    puts "Memory used: #{measure_memory - initial_memory} bytes"
  end
end

EDIT: I ran another test (below) to see number of Array allocations between the two methods. Both allocated around 50,000 Arrays, with sporadically ~3,000 arrays. I'm not sure if this test is correctly measuring what I need.
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'objspace'

class TestWithMethodMissing
  def method_missing(*)
    nil
  end

  #  OR

  # def method_missing(...)
  #   nil
  # end
end

runs = 100_000

def test_array_allocations(runs)
  total_allocations = 0

  runs.times do
    before_arrays = ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_ARRAY]

    test_object = TestWithMethodMissing.new
    test_object.some_undefined_method(1, 'test', :symbol)

    after_arrays = ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_ARRAY]

    total_allocations += (after_arrays - before_arrays)
  end

  average_allocations = total_allocations / runs.to_f
  { total_allocations: total_allocations, average_allocations: average_allocations }
end

p test_array_allocations(runs)


From the docs:  "Also, note that a bare * can be used to ignore arguments"

I guess any answer would be opinionated. I would use an anonymous splat, because   it already indicates in the method signature that the arguments will not be used. Whereas the argument forwarding requires the reader to scan the whole method to understand that the arguments are actually not used. Readability and understandability of code is certainly more important in most case than its performance.

Thanks @Stefan, I saw that in the docs, but it makes no mention of Array allocation. It made me wonder if anonymous splat is at all optimized to avoid an allocation when it sees I'm not passing it to another method, or if the docs is just rephrasing the old practice of using splats to group ignored arguments. ex: def method_missing(*args); end;

@spickermann, the anonymous splat can be passed to others methods, so it also requires the reader to scan the whole method. But yes, based on the docs, and the fact that ... is called argument forwarding, I have a preference for the splat, too. But was wondering if there's any optimization when the splat is not passed to another method. The docs don't make that clear.

@flavio the bare * is very idiomatic of your request. While you are correct that this can be passed to other methods, there are many things in ruby that are based on the appearance of something rather than its functional capacity for instance methods that end in a bang (!) are "dangerous", generally mutative, methods that start with an underscore (_) are generally indicative of private, methods that end in a question mark (?) should return a boolean, blocks using an underscore (each {|_,v|) indicate the variable will not be used, etc...

...None of these are enforced by the language they are simply well held convention that can be easily parsed by a ruby developer. Failure to adhere to the convention is obviously permissible but would create confusion for future developers. Many have appropriated the C adage, that: "Ruby provides you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot".

@engineersmnky, thank you. I'm going with the splat.

The official docs suggests using the bare * to ignore arguments, so that appears to be the longstanding convention and is more idiomatic.
